# Replace Null value of active date from previous date values

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to write sql query for below Result:

I have below table:

```
Amount          Date    Code
100         01-11-2014  USD
200         02-11-2014  USD
200         02-11-2014  INR
NULL        03-11-2014  NULL
NULL        04-11-2014  NULL
200         05-11-2014  INR
NULL        06-11-2014  NULL
NULL        07-11-2014  NULL
200         08-11-2014  USD
```

I need below result:

When the Amount is NULL for a given date, then need to show Amount as Zero for both the codes.
Here for the date 03-11-2014, the Amount is NULL, so in the output, there are two rows for that date one for US and one for INR with Amount as Zero.

```
Amount  Date    Code

100 01-11-2014  USD
200 02-11-2014  USD
200 02-11-2014  INR
0   03-11-2014  USD
0   03-11-2014  INR
0   04-11-2014  USD
0   04-11-2014  INR
200 05-11-2014  INR
0   06-11-2014  INR
0   07-11-2014  INR
200 08-11-2014  USD
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select isnull(Amount,0) as amount,  Date,    Code
from table
```

Comment: Please check result data for date 03-11-2014 and also check code

Comment: @user3744032 what is logic behind this??

Answer (score 0):

Need to use `CROSS APPLY` to get values for the CODES as Zero where Amount is NULL.

```
SELECT Amount, DATE, code
FROM Table1 WHERE Amount is not NULL
UNION
SELECT 0, DATE , A.Code
FROM Table1 
CROSS APPLY ( SELECT distinct Code from Table1 where code is NOT NULL) A
WHERE Amount IS NULL 
ORDER By Date
```

Comment: Please check result data for date 03-11-2014

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach.  Enumerate the rows where `code` is `NULL`.  When the code is null and the sequential value is 1, then `'USD'`, when 2, then `'INR'`.  The following uses `amount` for the indicator of missing data for both `amount` and `code`:

```
select (case when amount is null then amount else 0 end) as amount,
       date,
       (case when amount is not null then code
             when seqnum = 1 then 'USD'
             when seqnum = 2 then 'INR'
        end) as code
from (select t1.*,
             row_number() over (partition by date, amount order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from table1 t1
     ) t
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query, that makes use of an outer apply, will give you what you want:

```
SELECT COALESCE(Amount, 0), t1.Dates, 
       CASE WHEN t1.Code IS NOT NULL THEN t1.Code
            ELSE t2.Code
       END As Code
FROM MyTable AS t1
OUTER APPLY (
SELECT Dates, Code, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY t.Dates DESC) AS DatesRank
FROM MyTable AS t
WHERE t1.Code IS NULL AND t.Code IS NOT NULL AND t1.Dates > t.Dates 
) t2
Where DatesRank IS NULL OR DatesRank = 1
```

The basic idea behind the above query is to perform an `OUTER APPLY` only when Code is null. When an `OUTER APPLY` is performed, then we join the 'problematic' record with all the records that:

- 'Belong to the same date' (e.g. (200, '2014-11-02', 'USD'), (200, '2014-11-02', 'INR'),
  ) AND
- 'Are non problematic' (i.e. have a code that is not null) AND
- 'Are the first ones that precede the problematic record'.

I hope I did not confuse you! :=)

P.S. The above query will work even if you have more currency cases in your data, e.g. 
(200, '2014-11-02', 'USD'), (200, '2014-11-02', 'INR'), (200, '2014-11-02', 'EUR').

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your scenario in [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/78653/24) and reached certain limit to your desired output:
Please have a look at your input and desired output in above hyperlink.

```
select ISNULL(c.Amount,d.Amount),c.MyDate,ISNULL(c.Code,d.Code) from 
sample c
left outer join 
(
select COALESCE(a.Amount,0) as Amount,
ISNULL(b.mydate,a.MyDate) as Mydate,
ISNULL(a.Code,'USD') as Code
from 
sample a
left outer join
(select Amount,MyDate,Code
from sample where Code = 'USD') b
on a.MyDate=b.MyDate
where a.Amount IS NULL
union all
select COALESCE(a.Amount,0) as Amount,
ISNULL(b.mydate,a.MyDate) as Mydate,
ISNULL(a.Code,'INR') as Code
from 
sample a
left outer join
(select Amount,MyDate,Code
from sample where Code = 'INR') b
on a.MyDate=b.MyDate
where a.Amount IS NULL) d
on c.Mydate = d.Mydate
```